# TYPO3 feedback / guestbook

Tags: typo3, feedback

Hello to all TYPO3 enthusiasts,

I am asking myself since about 2 weeks now, how to make a feedback/guestbook page with TYPO3.

**What I want:**

I have a page, where visitors can leave a feedback.
When they send a feedback, it shall not be showed immediately. It shall be stored in a database, with a flag "allowed: yes/no". If the administrator allows the visitors feedback, it shall appear on the page.

The feedbacks, that haven't yet been allowed, shall be displayed in the backend, where they can be enabled.

**My problem**

I don't even know, if this is realizable? If it is, what is the next step to make this working? Do i have to create my own extension for that?

Would be very nice, if someone can answer me my question and maybe give me some advices.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://bitbucket.org/ArminVieweg/pw_comments/overview

The current master version should be capable of doing this for TYPO3 7.6

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sadly pw_comments is not up-to-date, so it only works for 6.2.0 - 7.2.99.

Comment: That's why I added the git repository URL. Master is compatible with 7.6

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me what you mean? xD Do i have to install something before i can install pw_comments?

Comment: Download the extension https://bitbucket.org/ArminVieweg/pw_comments/downloads and just upload it manualy to `typo3conf/ext/pw_comments`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a third one :-)

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mmc_guestbook

I tested that and it worked for me, I think it should also work on 7.6 so you can just ignore the requirements.

Since I needed some changes I rewrote most of the code and my version is working on 7.6. Write a comment if you want me version.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I would really like to see your version to make it running on 7.6 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Download and install extension tt_guest from TYPO3 extensions repository
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tt_guest
This would offer the funktionality you described

Comment: I ave installed tt_guest, but I have to say that this extension doesn't work properly, or i am making some mistakes (incidentally noted: the manual for this extension leaves much to be desired!). Is there any other way beside this extension?